# Select Groups and Subgroups and Groups of Subgroups in SQL with single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of `Groups` there are around 1000 groups and subgroups they have relation with `parent_id` i want to select the group by id with their childs and childs of child groups this is `5 level` groups.I have query which return the one child i want to return all level of groups with single query is it possible if yes then how ?

[image]

Comment: A self join would be the way to go ;).

Comment: show you data scheda, a set of sample data and the aspected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off what you have provided, you could do the following:

```
SELECT a.group_name as 'Parent category', b.group_name as 'Sub-category 1' , c.group_name as 'Sub-category 2' , d.group_name as 'Sub-category 3' , e.group_name as 'Sub-category 4'
FROM Groups a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups b ON a.group_id = b.parent
LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups c ON b.parent = c.parent
LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups d ON c.parent = d.parent
LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups e ON d.parent = e.parent;
```

This would have one result per subgroup (a join would get you one sub category)

Comment: yes @Matt this works thankyou :) , i have a one more question if i want to get all levels (5 levels) can i have to repeat this query for 5 levels ?

Comment: yeah works i putt 5 joins and it works :) thankyou @Matt :)